# Acelerómetro en QML

Tags: qt

Intento medir distancia basado la aceleración (acelerómetro de un móvil) los datos que muestra es de metros sobre segundos al cuadro (m/s<sup>2</sup>). Si eso es cierto:

```
Accelerometer {
    id: accel
    dataRate: 1000 / 25
    onReadingChanged: {
        console.log(reading.x, reading.y, reading.z);
    }
}
```

Ahora, cuando muestra la información y teniendo el móvil completamente quieto (sin movimiento). Muestra aceleración en todos los ejes, lo que es absurdo. ¿Alguno tiene idea del porqué?

Comment: Quizás te haga falta la fórmula de aceleración. ¿Puedes incluir la formula que usas?

Comment: Lo estas probando en un dispositivo? o algun emulador?

Comment: Yo hice una aplicación en android que muestra todos los sensores de mi celular, y con respecto al acelerometro te puedo contar que asi se comporta, los datos cambian constantemente aunque este totalmente quieto, lo que debes de observar es que los valores que muestra no tengan variaciones en mas de un entero. Si eso pasa entonces si esta mal, pero si solo cambian los decimales esta correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto mas tema de electrónica que de programación :D.

Es normal que los sensores te den lecturas constantemente, todo depende de la sensibilidad del sensor.  Si el sensor es muy sensible va a tener variaciones estando quieto.

Las lecturas que recibas estando quieto deberían ser pequeñas y de media 0 (es decir deberían darte valores positivos y negativos pequeños que si los sumases te darían 0). Pasa con TODOS los sensores de cualquier cosa (temperatura, luz, lo que fuera)

Solución? En estos casos lo más normal es usar una ventana de muestras y hacer la media de esa ventana. Es decir, cuando leas el sensor no uses directamente ese valor sino haz la media con las últimas N muestras que hayas leído. Te vas guardando las N últimas muestras en un vector y ya está, es fácil de implementar.

Que tamaño tiene que tener N? Depende de tu aplicación, de tu sensor y de la distribución de la gravedad en el planeta en el que vivas :D, por lo tanto ves probando. 
Si N es muy grande el sensor va a ser poco reactivo y los cambios rápidos no los va a ver. 
Si N es muy pequeña vas a tener ese ruido de fondo que a veces puede volver loco.

Todo es ir probando hasta que encuentres una N que vaya bien. Te recomiendo mínimo 3 y máximo 10, pero deberás probarlo para ver como te va funcionando.

Ya explicarás como ha ido.